# On remote: fatal: Path does no exist Git error

Tags: git

When new file is added to my local repo, it seems that each time i push to remote, i get

```
remote: fatal: Path 'src/main/java/com/a/b/File.java' does not exist in 'branch'
```

Then, from what i can observe new file is added to remote and all is well.

This, however looks like a fatal warning to me, what with `fatal` and all.

Am i reading this incorrectly? Is this an error or a warning one can safely ignore?

Comment: Are you committing the changes before you push?

Answer (score 1):

Everything should be fine if you add the new files with 'git add File.java'. I follow that with 'git commit -m "message"'.

Pro Tip (I'm not really a pro yet): Instead of 'add' followed by 'commit', use 'git commit -a -m "message"', as long as you know that all the necessary definitions are in your .gitignore file. You don't want to accidentally add and commit temp files and such.